# I am getting this exception: Object does not exist at location

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

```
 E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
    Object does not exist at location.
     Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404
2021-09-13 00:52:49.705 20328-20869/com.dishanamdev.advibe E/StorageException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",    "status": "GET_OBJECT"  }}
    java.io.IOException: {  "error": {    "code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object",    "status": "GET_OBJECT"  }}
```

and my security rules in firebase storage are

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

My java code. Here, I am not able to understand that what to write in place of `b` and what to write in place of `bucket` written in `firebase storage rules`.
Could you please tell me, what to write in those two above-mentioned places as compared to my java code?
I tried to write `user` in place of `b` and `currentID` in place of `bucket`, but it didn't work.
In this way :

```
rules_version = '2';
    service firebase.storage {
      match /user/{currentID}/o {
        match /{allPaths=**} {
          allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
        }
      }
    }



 public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        String currentId = user.getUid();
        DocumentReference reference;
        FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

        reference = firestore.collection("user").document(currentId);

        reference.get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        if(task.getResult().exists()){

                            String nameResult = task.getResult().getString("name");
                            String bioResult = task.getResult().getString("bio");

                            nameET.setText(nameResult);
                            bioET.setText(bioResult);
                        }else{
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),CreateProfile.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
                });}
```

Please help me.

Comment: This is not an issue with your security rules. The file you're trying to retrieve does not exist. Please verify that the path points to a valid object in your storage bucket

Comment: Could you provide me any documentation link from where I can learn how to write the correct path?

Comment: error clearly state : code": 404,    "message": "Not Found.  Could not get object. may your path is wrong as mentioned above by the Frank.

Comment: Please show your code that is throwing the error and how you're trying to get the object from storage

Comment: I right now did sir. Please check once and please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right Now, I solved this problem. This error appears when we are not uploading the object which contains all the data (including photos, texts, etc..) in the firebase.So if anyone else is getting the same problem `then must check your code again` in the class of java file where you have created the firebase storage reference, database reference, document reference